# code works to a point

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

The following code looks good to me but works to a point. The function should display the grade levels of students based on exam performance but it does not run the last two else statements and so, if a student scores lower than 50 the function still displays "pass".

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stud_Result(integer,numeric) RETURNS text
AS 
$$
DECLARE
    stuNum ALIAS FOR $1;
    grade ALIAS FOR $2;
    result TEXT;
BEGIN
    IF grade >= 70.0 THEN SELECT 'distinction' INTO result FROM student,entry
        WHERE student.sno = entry.sno AND student.sno = stuNum;

    ELSIF grade >=50.0 OR grade <=70.0 THEN SELECT 'pass' INTO result FROM student,entry
        WHERE student.sno = entry.sno AND student.sno = stuNum;

    ELSIF grade >0 OR grade< 50.0 THEN SELECT 'fail' INTO result FROM student,entry
        WHERE student.sno = entry.sno AND student.sno = stuNum;

    ELSE SELECT 'NOT TAKEN' INTO result FROM student,entry
        WHERE student.sno = entry.sno AND student.sno = stuNum;
    END IF;

    RETURN result;
END;$$
LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Can anyone point me to the problem?

Comment: If I were you, the first thing I would try would be a *smaller* function. Make one that does nothing, see if *that* works. Then you can tell whether it's (a) a problem with creating functions, or (b) a problem in the function you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

This is a PostgreSQL gotcha that has tripped me up as well.  You need to replace your `ELSE IF`s with `ELSIF`.

You're seeing that error because each successive `ELSE IF` is being interpreted as starting a nested `IF` block, which expects its own `END IF;`.

See [the documentation on conditionals](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-CONDITIONALS) for more information on the proper syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic in the conditionals is a bit strange. You have these:

- `grade >= 70.0`
- `grade >= 50.0 OR grade <= 70.0`
- `grade >  0    OR grade <  50.0`

Note that zero satisfies the second condition as do a lot of other values that you don't want in that branch of the conditonal. I think you want these:

- `grade >= 70.0`
- `grade >= 50.0 AND grade <= 70.0`
- `grade >  0    AND grade <  50.0`

You also seem to be using your SELECTs to check if the person is in the course but if the `grade` is given and they're not in the course, you will end up with a NULL `result`. Either the "in the course" check should be outside your function or you should convert a NULL `result` to `'NOT TAKEN'` before returning.

This looks like homework so I'm not going to be anymore explicit than this.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, I don't think it is a good idea to hide data in code. Data belongs in tables:

```
SET search_path='tmp';

-- create some data
DROP TABLE tmp.student CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE tmp.student
    ( sno INTEGER NOT NULL
    , grade INTEGER
    , sname varchar
    );
INSERT INTO tmp.student(sno) SELECT generate_series(1,10);
UPDATE tmp.student SET grade = sno*sno;

DROP TABLE tmp.entry CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE tmp.entry
    ( sno INTEGER NOT NULL
    , sdate TIMESTAMP
    );
INSERT INTO tmp.entry(sno) SELECT generate_series(1,10);

-- table with interval lookup
DROP TABLE tmp.lookup CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE tmp.lookup
    ( llimit NUMERIC NOT NULL
    , hlimit NUMERIC
    , result varchar
    );

INSERT INTO lookup (llimit,hlimit,result)  VALUES(70, NULL, 'Excellent'), (50, 70, 'Passed'), (30, 50, 'Failed')
    ;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION stud_result(integer,numeric) RETURNS text
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    stunum ALIAS FOR $1;
    grade ALIAS FOR $2;
    result TEXT;
BEGIN

SELECT COALESCE(lut.result, 'NOT TAKEN')  INTO result
    FROM student st, entry en
    LEFT JOIN lookup lut ON (grade >= lut.llimit
                    AND (grade < lut.hlimit OR lut.hlimit IS NULL) )
    WHERE st.sno = en.sno
     AND st.sno = stunum
    ;
  RETURN result;
END; $BODY$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;

-- query joining students with their function values
SELECT st.*
    , stud_result (st.sno, st.grade)
    FROM student st
    ;
```

But wait: you can just as well do without the ugly function:

```
-- Plain query
SELECT
    st.sno, st.sname, st.grade
    , COALESCE(lut.result, 'NOT TAKEN') AS result
    FROM student st
    LEFT JOIN lookup lut ON ( 1=1
        AND   lut.llimit <= st.grade
        AND ( lut.hlimit > st.grade OR lut.hlimit IS NULL)
        )
    JOIN entry en ON st.sno = en.sno
    ;
```

Results:

```
 sno | grade | sname | stud_result 
-----+-------+-------+-------------
   1 |     1 |       | NOT TAKEN
   2 |     4 |       | NOT TAKEN
   3 |     9 |       | NOT TAKEN
   4 |    16 |       | NOT TAKEN
   5 |    25 |       | NOT TAKEN
   6 |    36 |       | Failed
   7 |    49 |       | Failed
   8 |    64 |       | Passed
   9 |    81 |       | Excellent
  10 |   100 |       | Excellent
(10 rows)

 sno | sname | grade |  result   
-----+-------+-------+-----------
   1 |       |     1 | NOT TAKEN
   2 |       |     4 | NOT TAKEN
   3 |       |     9 | NOT TAKEN
   4 |       |    16 | NOT TAKEN
   5 |       |    25 | NOT TAKEN
   6 |       |    36 | Failed
   7 |       |    49 | Failed
   8 |       |    64 | Passed
   9 |       |    81 | Excellent
  10 |       |   100 | Excellent
(10 rows)
```

Comment: Well, students have to learn style and design, too... (but maybe in some countries it's just "do what the teacher says" , even if it is plain nonsense)

Comment: Long enough to know how to screw up somebody else's homework.

Answer (score -1):

Get rid of the function altogether and use a query:

```
SELECT 
  s.*, 
  CASE e.grade 
    WHEN >= 0 AND < 50 THEN 'failed'
    WHEN >= 50 AND < 70 THEN 'passed'
    WHEN >= 70 AND <= 100 THEN 'excellent'
    ELSE 'not taken'
  END
FROM 
 student s,
 entry e
WHERE
 s.sno = e.sno;
```

Comment: Please, if you down vote this, add a comment why. Using a function for this is just not the way to do it.